# Auto add 0 to the int field - mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm building some application, which is connected to mysql database.

In mysql in let say table `test` I have an Integer field called `myId`.

With my first insert to the myId value "1" is added, with my second insert i'm adding value "20".

Now my question is: is there any possibility, that to the first value "1" after second insert will be auto added "0".

So i will have:

```
|myId|
 10
 20
```

And if a add "300", so to the two first inserts will be added next 0 ?

```
|myId|
 100
 200
 300
```

Comment: like "on insert set myId = myId*10"?

Comment: You can write a trigger for insertions, check if your condition met inside it, and update previous values if so.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it when you select data

```
set @max:=(select max(length(myId)) from your_table);
SELECT myId * power(10, (@max - length(myId))) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

unverified:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER upd_entries AFTER INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
     update your_table 
     set myId = myId * power(10, ((select * from (select max(length(myId)) from your_table)) - length(myId)));
END;
|
delimiter ;
```